# Why useState cause re-render so many times

Tags: reactjs

I am investigating why the `useState` cause render so many time like the following app, or [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/festive-chandrasekhar-4l8zw)

```js
import React from "react";

export default function App() {
  const [name, setName] = React.useState("unknown");
  console.log("render...", name);
  React.useEffect(() => {
    const doIt = async () => {
      await new Promise(res => setTimeout(res, 1000));
      setName("Ron");
    };
    doIt();
  }, []);
  return <div className="App">{name}</div>;
}
```

I think it should render 2 times, 1 is for initial, plus the useEffect. But why it actually render 4 times as below?

```
render... unknown 
render... unknown 
render... Ron 
render... Ron
```

Comment: your output like this because componentDidMount execute after the render method

Answer (score 2):

The console statement is in the function body, `React` will execute the function body on each render.

1. On component mount, As the init state is empty, the console will print an empty string.
2. As you are updating the state on component Mount, `React` will execute the function body again and then log the state with the updated value.

> As you are using the `React.StrictMode` it can render the component more than once. That is the reason you see the console logs multiple times.

> The commit phase is usually very fast, but rendering can be slow. For this reason, the upcoming concurrent mode (which is not enabled by default yet) breaks the rendering work into pieces, pausing and resuming the work to avoid blocking the browser. This means that React may invoke render phase lifecycles more than once before committing, or it may invoke them without committing at all (because of an error or a higher priority interruption).
> Render phase lifecycles include the following class component methods:

1. constructor
2. componentWillMount (or UNSAFE_componentWillMount)
3. componentWillReceiveProps (or UNSAFE_componentWillReceiveProps)
4. componentWillUpdate (or UNSAFE_componentWillUpdate)
5. getDerivedStateFromProps
6. shouldComponentUpdate render
7. setState updater functions (the first argument)

> **Because the above methods might be called more than once**, it’s important that they do not contain side-effects. Ignoring this rule can lead to a variety of problems, including memory leaks and invalid application state. Unfortunately, it can be difficult to detect these problems as they can often be non-deterministic.

You can read more about `React.StrictMode` [here](https://reactjs.org/docs/strict-mode.html)

Comment: please upvote and accept my answer, if it solves your problem

Answer (score 0):

This is because you are doing `setState` in `useEffect` without any dependency. So whenever you component is rendering, the use effect is working as `componentDidMount` and then inside of this, there is a `setState` which cause another rerender and again it calls `componentDidmount`. Its kinda looping the whole process.